# Cookies what created in iframe reset after parent page reloaded

Tags: javascript, php

I have a index.php and a hidden iframe inside it. When someone on the main page clicks on something then JavaScript changes the iframe's src attribute. For example, a user clicks on link1 and JavaScript changes `iframe src='update.php?clicked=1'` and update.php saves into a cookie) but when the parent page is reloaded all cookies data is lost.

The cookie path is "/", update.php is in same directory than index.php, so it should work, shouldn't it? As long as the parent page isn't refreshed everything works.

Comment: Can we see some example code, it would help work out what you're after?

Comment: php session erases itself when the session was ended. Dunno if thats the case here.

Answer (score 0):

problem was the p3p, so needed Platform for Privacy Preferences Project header

in php like this

header('P3P:CP="IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT"');

http://viralpatel.net/blogs/how-to-set-third-party-cookies-with-iframe/